# How to populate data in a twitter-bootstrap modal using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

**Using**:

-*Twitter-Bootstrap*

-*AngularJs*

Here's the story

Created table: rows are dynamically created using "ng-repeat". The data item inside the first cell (in a row) has an on-click event triggering a Twitter-Bootstrap modal to appear. The input fields in the modal match the columns in the [table] row. The user edits the necessary data in that row. This should update database and changes reflect immediately in the table.

However, I cannot get the data from the table to populate inside the modal fields.

Here's the weird thing... If I use a Twitter-Bootstrap (TBS) popup instead of a TBS modal, everything works. **EVERYTHING**. All the data populates inside the popup fields, it's editable, it actually saves to the database, AND updates the table row! But popups suck and I am restricted from using them.

Using the EXACT SAME code, why won't the data populate inside a modal?
Obviously, this leads me to believe using syntactically identical code, a popup and modal do not function the same way. But why?

The research I've done, and documentation I've perused on here as well as both TBS and AngularJS, has been either too overwhelming or altogether unhelpful.

In Summary, this is the functionality I'm looking to achieve:

- User clicks the data inside the first cell of a table row
- *(on-click) Modal appears **populated** with the data in the row* (particularly this).
- User can edit the fields
- Save/Update.  The trigger event can be "enter" or button "on-click"  I don't care, I just want it to work.

Here's the gist of the code (with the popup which works, and the modal which doesn't).

Disclaimer: I couldn't get it to work in here (SO or jfiddle) I'm probably missing a reference. But I know you all are smarter than me, and with what I've given, I have the utmost confidence in this community to be able to figure out what it is I'm doing wrong.

I thank you all in advance for your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="person">
<head>
    <title>HELP ME WITH MODALS</title>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <table style="border:1px solid black; padding:3px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Favorit Color</th>
                    <th>Favorit Food</th>
                    <th>Favorite Season</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-click="updatePerson(person)">
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">{{person.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.favoriteColor}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.favoriteFood}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.favoriteSeason}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-placement="left" popover-title="Edit" ng-click="current.person=person">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:#513011;">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit Person</h4>
                    </div>
                    <!--/HEADER-->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form ng-submit="update(current.person)">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                                <input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model=current.person.firstName class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                                <input name="lastname" type="text" ng-model=current.person.lastName class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="favoritecolor">Favorite Color:</label>
                                <input name="favoritecolor" type="text" ng-model=current.perosn.favoriteColor class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="favoritefood">Favorite Food:</label>
                                <input name="favoritefood" type="text" ng-model=current.perosn.favoriteFood class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="favoriteseason">Favorite Season:</label>
                                <input name="favoriteseason" type="text" ng-model=current.perosn.favoriteSeason class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--/MODAL-BODY-->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" ng-click="update(current.person)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                    </div>
                    <!--/MODAL-FOOTER-->
                </div>
                <!--/MODAL-CONTENT-->
            </div>
            <!--/MODAL-DIALOG-->
        </div>
        <!--/MODAL-->
    </div>
    <!--/CONTROLLER-->
</body>
</html>


<!-- script for edit popover-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popoverTemplate.html">
    <div>
        <form ng-submit="update(current.person)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                <input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model=current.person.firstName class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastname">LastName:</label>
                <input name="lastname" type="text" ng-model=current.person.lastName class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="favoritecolor">Favorite Color:</label>
                <input name="favoritecolor" type="text" ng-model=current.person.favoritecolor class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="favoritefood">Favorite Food:</label>
                <input name="favoritefood" type="text" ng-model=current.person.favoritecolor class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="favoriteseason">Favorite Season:</label>
                <input name="favoriteseason" type="text" ng-model=current.person.favoritecolor class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="delete(current.schoolTerm)" value="Delete">
        </form>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    var person = angular.module('person', []);
    personApp.controller('PersonCtrl', [
    function ($scope) {
        var person = [
            {
                'firstName': 'Christine',
                'lastName': 'Smith',
                'favoriteColor': 'Pink',
                'favoriteFood': 'Sushi',
                'favoriteSeason': 'Summer'
            },
            {
                'firstName': 'Dana',
                'lastName': 'Carvey',
                'favoriteColor': 'Yellow',
                'favoriteFood': 'Tomatoes',
                'favoriteSeason': 'Summer'
            },
            {
                'firstName': 'Terry',
                'lastName': 'Gross',
                'favoriteColor': 'Chartreuse',
                'favoriteFood': 'Lasagna',
                'favoriteSeason': 'Spring'
            }
        ];

    }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the modal in the twitter bootstrap and pass data back and forth, you have to extend/wrap it around with your own directives, and I don't recommend doing that since there are already directives that do just that.

If you are new to Angular, and Have to use bootstrap consider using Angular Ui Bootstrap , which is a set of custom directives written using the twitter bootstrap.

If you are not supporting IE8 and haven't committed to twitter bootstrap, I strongly encourage you checkout lumx.

Note: These two are both still in beta, so use with caution.

Okay, now lets get back to your question. If you decide to stay with twitter bootstrap and once you have the angular ui bootstrap installed - it's easy, just follow this steps https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#installation - , the only thing that probably will be a little confusing at first would be how to pass your scope properties from the caller controller up to the modal. 
In a nutshell you have to do something like this in the caller controller:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
templateUrl: 'yourModalTemplate.html',
controller: 'yourModalController',
resolve: {
    itemsFromCallerController: function () {
        return [{ i: 1, i: 2 }];
    }
}
```

and your modal's controller should look something like this:

```
angular.module("app").controller('yourModalInstanceController', function ($scope, $modalInstance, itemsFromCallerController, action) {
    $scope.modalHeader = "your modal header";
    $scope.items = itemsFromCallerController;
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Take a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/93XZqB5pMVX72TRZBdAh?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you! I initially had trouble because I didn't have the cancel and ok functions built into my modal (yet). That was preventing it from populating the data. Once I commented it out for later tweaking it worked great. Thank you!!